# Setup dual monitor and dual laptops with kvm switch (VGA)

Tags: vga, dvi, kvm-switch

I was wondering how would I set up 2 Monitors (1 with DVI & VGA the other with DP/HDMI/DVI) and set it up with a KVM switch. KVM switch has 3 VGA ports, 2 for PC1 and PC2 and the other for console. I also have two laptops that are on docking stations. For instance lets say i'm trying to get Laptop 1 to display on 2 monitors and if I wanted to, once I hit the switch, have Laptop 2 to display on 1 monitor and have Laptop 1 display on the other? Is that possible? I'm setting up a workplace for work and not sure how to set it up. 1 Docking station contains 1 VGA and DP and the other has a VGA and 2 DP. Thanks!

Comment: 1 docking station contains VGA, (2) DVI and DP. The other docking station has 2 DP's and 1 VGA.

Comment: Please clarify by clicking [edit]. Do you want Monitor A to _always_ show the output of docked Laptop 1, and Monitor B shows either docked laptop 1 or docked laptop 2?

Comment: Is this still an open question?  I don't see a green checkmark.  I have some ideas on solutions.  One idea is a KVM switch like this one: https://www.startech.com/en-us/server-management/sv231ddvdua

Answer (score 1):

A KVM switch will only let you display on 1 monitor at a time (1 output).

So if you buy another KVM switch(with 3 DVI ports or 2 DVI and one DP).

You will be able to switch monitors however you like, if you would plug your DVI and VGA cables of each pc in separate switches.